# AJAX with JSON and PHP not returning any data... I think

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Why does my code not work?

I know I am sending data,

But there is no response.

### jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").submit(function () {

                var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;
                var pword = document.getElementById("password").value;
                var postData = {
                    username: uname,
                    password: pword
                };
                var PostDataString = JSON.stringify(postData);
                alert(PostDataString);

            $.ajax({
               url: "test.php",
               type: "GET",
               data: PostDataString,
               dataType: 'json',
               contentType: 'json',
               cache: false,
               success: function (ReturnData) {
                    alert("Yay!");
               } 
            });
    });
    });
```

---

### PHP

```
$json = $_GET["PostDataString"];
$jsonarray = json_decode($json, true);
echo $jsonarray;
```

---

Comment: did you mean to GET or POST? Your options object looks a little confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json_decode` is for turning a JSON string into PHP constructs.  `json_encode` does the opposite and is what you want.  You are expecting a json data type on the JavaScript side; jQuery will throw an error if it does not get valid JSON in that case.

The `JSON.stringify` conversion is unnecessary since `$.ajax` accepts a JavaScript object for its `data` attribute.  In fact, stringifying the JSON prevents it from being sent as any parameter.

If you remove `JSON.stringify` and just send `postData` as-is.  You can access `$_GET['username']` and `$_GET['password']`, but no others.

Comment: But now a new problem arises. How do I return the GET data? What I mean is now that I can access the data in my php, how do I return it to the $.ajax function to work with the response?

Comment: @copilot0910 it depends .. wildly.  What would be best for you to have in `ReturnData`?  An object like `{username: "username", password: "password"}`?  If so, use `json_encode(array('username' => $_GET['username'], 'password' => $_GET['password']))`

Comment: I need to return the array, so yes.

Comment: But still the problem arrises. When I try to alert anything after the data comes back from the PHP, I am getting nothing.